# Android App : White space in the top screen

Tags: android

White blank space in the android app. YELLOW highlighted area

[image]

XML as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.home.CustomerFragment">

    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/search_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:background="@color/black_overlay"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/customer_view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/customer_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingBottom="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/search_view" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I tried to change few things, but in the constraint layout, I couldn't remove that white space

EDIT-1

See the full screen image, in the bottom I have the three panel that hold three button for my application tabs

[image]

Comment: Try to remove 
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/customer_view"

Comment: No luck, even after that I see that space... I've the screen like this... Updated post

Comment: That's akward.. I tried exactly the same code on my android studio, and there was no space above the search bar. Try again removing things and checking the results, and make sure that the code you provide is the right one.

Comment: I gave the right code, just to avoid showing up the data I took the screenshot from order tab